# Reason[internalError] Domain[global] ]

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm getting tones of these very generic errors in my solution while accessing the Google Drive service via the SDK.

Can anyone provide pointers as to why these errors are happening?  For the most part the solution works but then randomly these exceptions will just pop up!

Maybe if I can email support directly that would be great :)

Also, over the last hour I've received in excess of 600 occurrences of this exception and really need to resolve it!

Comment: welcome to developing with Drive. It has days like this.